# Can MooTools usage in asp.net for validator input?

Tags: asp.net, mootools

I have dialog box with jquery within some textbox input but i need use mootools validator for validator input, Mootools script are loaded but validator nor work.

This my code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEvent('domready', function(){
        new FormCheck('myform');
        });
</script>
```

```
<asp:textbox id="tbVisitTopic" CssClass="validate['required']" runat="server" Width="300px">
```

```
<asp:button id="btAddDetail" class="button submit" Width="55px" Runat="server" Text="Tambah"><br>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: 'not work' is not exactly a good description of a problem. what does not work? do you get exceptions? does form submission not stop? does it not run through your validators? where is the FormCheck plugin you used homepage/project page/github page (it's not standard mootools)? what version of mootools? is jquery in noConflict mode? can you build a jsfiddle? can you show RENDERED html and not ASP tags

Answer (score 1):

Did you change any of the defaults of FormCheck?

What version of MooTools are you using? If its the latest 1.3+ FormCheck will fail as it relies on mootools 1.2 code base. Make sure to use mootools WITH compatabilty with the latest version of FormCheck.

Or I did port formcheck awhile back to 1.4 and you can find the codebase here:

http://www.timwickstrom.com/client-side-code/mootools/moofloor-formcheck-for-mootools-1-4-x/

(Same Docs and options apply)

FYI Form check is Awesome!

Comment: what does it have over From.Validator from mootools-more?

Comment: What initially brought me to its UI, that was before I really dug into JS and Moo in particualr. Partially this is a fail over from tools that I take with me. However it is a little lighter and has more built in validators (regex). You can see a list of public methods here: http://mootools.floor.ch/docs/formcheck/files/formcheck-js.html